# Using foreach with mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with two columns; `id` and `type`.  I'm trying to retrieve those values to use in a select list of values (aka drop down list).  Outside of my html, this php works perfectly:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usertype`";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($type_lov = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo '<pre>', print_r($type_lov,true), '</pre>';
};
```

Output from php above:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [type] => System Admin ) 
Array ( [id] => 2 [type] => System Admin2 ) 
Array ( [id] => 3 [type] => System Admin3 ) 
Array ( [id] => 4 [type] => Account Admin ) 
Array ( [id] => 5 [type] => Account User )
```

To get it into the SELECT / OPTIONS tags, I attempted several things unsuccessfully.  The two attempts that made the most sense to me (but that did not work) were:

```
<!--ATTEMPT 1-->    
<select>
    <?php while ($type_lov = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        foreach ($type_lov as $id=>$type) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $type; ?></option>
        <?php };
    }; ?>
</select>

<!--ATTEMPT 2-->
<select>
    <?php foreach ($type_lov = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) as $id=>$type) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $type; ?></option>
    <?php }; ?>
</select>
```

Neither worked.  What is the proper way to go about this?

Comment: did not work... how?

Comment: Could you please post your dumped array?

Comment: Added the array dump from the php at the top of the post.  You'll see I'm successfully connecting to the database, and can retrieve and print_r the arrays.  When I try and get the contents of the array, specifically the [type] values, into the Select field, it doesn't work.  The Select field appears on the page, but is empty.  Suggestons 1 and 2 below have the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. It returns it's data as an associative array, meaning your table columns are used as indices for the array.

Furthermore, why are you coupling while with foreach in your first example? What's the thought process that you went on?

Anyway, this should help you on your journey:

```
<select>
    <?php
        while (($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)))
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $data['id'] . '">' . $data['type'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I remember reading that it is bad practice to use the function in the loop itself and that it's better to define a variable that contains the data and then loop through that because if the former case the function is run every time the loop is run. Is this true?

Comment: @ConstantineLoukas: The function needs to be run every time since it grabs the next data (using an internal iterator). Have a look at the php [myqsli_fetch_assoc page](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for further reference. Generally speaking: For functions that always return the same data it wouldn't be ideal of course.

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot. I thought mysqli_fetch_assoc returned all the data at once. Thanks

Comment: ccKep: I was coupling while with foreach in my first example out of desperation.  Other examples I've seen always use foreach to generate the select list of values.  I too can do it with an associative array when I build the array manually.  But pulling the list from the database has been a different story.  Tried your suggestion, and couldn't get it to work.  Any other ideas?  I updated my original post with the results of the pure php that appears at the top of my post.  Maybe that will help.

Comment: What's the exact output of my suggested code? (ie. if you replace the echo in your top code with mine and rename your `$type_lov` variable to `$data` in the while)

Comment: @ccKep: My apologies!  Your code did work.  Else where on the page I had another variable with the same name.  As soon as I made the variable unique, it began working.  Thank you for your assistance, and for being persistent with your answer.  Much appreciated!